# Specified resizing in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, scale

I'm just wondering:

[image]

This is the size of the group.

[image]

I want to resize the rectangle and the Q in the same time,
but I want to give a specified size for the rectangle that the q can follow.

[image]

For example the height of the rectangle is 320 px.
I want it to be 208 px with locked ratio. now I want the Q
to follow the changes, just like if i resize the group with the bounding box.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: White space, low contrasts, extra light small fonts are beautiful on artsy projects but terrible to read on screenshots! Your question will also be hard to search if you put them in your JPG.

Comment: That's true, sorry about that!
I just wanted to make easy to understand my question. Next time i write instead of drawing.
Anyway, the question is still unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

It's the easiest thing..

- select both objects
- open the transform tab
- make sure that Constain Width and Height Proportions is active
- type in the desired height
- press enter...

...and there you have it.
Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can select both objects at the same time.

1. Hold shift down with the selection tool and select both objects
2. Enable **scale tool**.
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click the point you want as reference
4. in scale dialog type `208/320 *100` (failing that type 65) in the uniform scale box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I can't write that in there. When I try, then hit enter, nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, but none of your answers working...

Comment: Ok try with new instructions.